# How to get values upto 2 decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have the following queries.

```
insert into tbl_percount([H1Cycle],[perOffshore],[perOnsite],[perTotal])
(select [H1Cycle],Round(cast([Offshore]*100.0/(select [Offshore] from tbl_FinalLastday where [H1Cycle]='H1 Total')as float),2) as 'perOffshore',
Round(cast([Onsite]*100.0/(select [Onsite] from tbl_FinalLastday where [H1Cycle]='H1 Total')as float),2) as 'perOnsite',
Round(cast([Total]*100.0/(select [Total] from tbl_FinalLastday where [H1Cycle]='H1 Total')as float),2) as 'perTotal'
 from tbl_FinalLastday where [H1Cycle]!='H1 Total')

 insert into tbl_percount([H1Cycle],[perOffshore],[perOnsite],[perTotal])
(select [H1Cycle],Round(cast([Offshore]*100/(select [Total]  from tbl_FinalLastday where [H1Cycle]='H1 Total')as float),2) as 'perOffshore',
Round(cast([Onsite]*100.0/(select [Total] from tbl_FinalLastday where [H1Cycle]='H1 Total')as float),2) as 'perOnsite',
Round(cast([Total]*100.0/(select [Total] from tbl_FinalLastday where [H1Cycle]='H1 Total')as float),2) as 'perTotal'
 from tbl_FinalLastday where [H1Cycle]='H1 Total')
```

[image]

### I want to insert the output into table 'tbl_percount'. In the first case it is giving me the correct output(first 4 rows).But in the second case(last row),insert query its giving the integer value by rounding off the decimal values.

---

I want the output as  71.00,29.00,100.00

How can I get this?

Comment: Do you want to _store_ two decimals of precision during insert, or do you want to _see_ two decimals of precision when selecting?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen:I want to store 2 decimals of precision.

Comment: cast to decimal(10,2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `cast` as `numeric(3,2)`, not as `float`.
try the following:

```
select cast(round([Offshore] * 100 / (
                SELECT [Total]
                FROM tbl_FinalLastday
                WHERE [H1Cycle] = 'H1 Total'
                ), 2) AS NUMERIC(3, 2)) AS 'perOffshore'
```

Comment: Should have been AS NUMERIC, please try again.